# How to track Fix Version on SNAPSHOT releases?

Tags: maven, jira

Suppose we have a Java project building with Maven and a JIRA issue tracker. Like always, we build snapshots (e.g. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) in between releases.

Now, we want to report a bug that occurs in one snapshot ('Affects Version'), assign it to a developer and finally resolve it ('Fix Version'). But, we don't have a dedicated project version declared for each build in the JIRA project, so we always fill in '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' for both version fields.

I feel there is nothing wrong in doing so. Yet the downside is, we cannot track the exact build that fixes the issue.

What would be best practices to achieve this?

Comment: Track the commit which solves the problem (name the issue in the commit) and which is related to a particular version in JIRA..After you have released the 1.0.0 you can rename the version in JIRA from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0. Apart from that I would always name the version 1.0.0 already and don't use 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with khmarbaise's comment.

The JIRA "Affects Version" and "Fix Version" are not really suited to track snapshot / buildnumbers. If you really want to track this for fix on a release in development, you can easily add a custom field, or just introduce the habit of mentioning the snapshot / buildnumber with the fix in a comment on the issue.